# Why was this character attacked in Agents of SHIELD?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, agents-of-shield

In *Turn, Turn, Turn* (S01E17), we pick up with

> Agent Garrett

being attacked by drones, sent by

> Victoria Hand,

who has also issued orders to capture our heroes.

We learn that

> Victoria believes Coulson is actually an agent of HYDRA

which explains why they were targeted. No similar argument is made regarding

> Agent Garrett

despite the fact that

> he actually is "The Clairvoyant" and a member of HYDRA.

Why was this other character targeted for termination prior to any evidence of ties/loyalty?

Answer (score 2):

> The reason he is attacked is because he worked WITH Coulson, and since Victoria Hand thought that Coulson was with Hydra then that means anybody connected with Coulson was most likely working with Hydra as well.  That is why she performed the test with Simmons in the lab to make sure that they were not part of Hydra.

Comment: Testing Simmons goes against your logic. They fired upon Garrett without any test of allegiance. Garrett also worked with Coulson in the past, but was not part of his team. Seems a bit of a stretch to assume that anyone Coulson had ever worked with was a member of HYDRA.

Comment: To me that's because they wanted Coulson.  Remember Hand was willing to kill everyone on board as soon as they got there.

Comment: @phantom42 Victoria Hand also warned her team about how resourceful Coulson's team is.  Regardless of whether or not the rest of the team was with Hydra, they were loyal to Coulson.

Comment: Surprised no one mentioned it, but Garrett had not only worked closely with Coulson, they were supposedly close friends going back for years.